# Joomla 2.5 advanced parameters

Tags: templates, joomla, parameters, components, joomla2.5

I am joomla 2.5 template developer and I want to use some custom template parameters for my theme. What I need is custom parameters fields like on this picture. I can't figure out how this is done. Is it a component placed inside parameters fields, or what it is.

[image]

My goal is to change templates css from admin backend to have opportunity to change each Position's width directly from "edit template" page. Do you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well that display is from a custom admin template --- if you are interested in adding template parameters you do that in templatedetails.xml, just add the fields you want. Beez2 provides a model for this.